# positioning with different heights

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

This mainly becomes an issue on alien ships. When I have a soldier on higher ground, if I want to move to the edge of the higher ground it moves the box to the lower floor. It's very difficult and sometimes impossible to get to certain tiles because it drops down to the next level.

Is there a way to force the movement target to stay on the current plane?

Answer (score 17):

You can control which floor you're going to using the mouse wheel.

Alien ships, however, do have the annoying tendency to have strange architecture which confuses the floor-selection mechanism. My work-around is to play with both the mouse-wheel to control the floor and <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd> to control the angle, until I get my cursor in a location where there's nothing behind it, so it *has* to choose the upper floor.

The same can be done with the dpad on consoles or on a gamepad for windows.

Comment: Yeah, I use the mouse wheel and q/e, but as you said, the strange architecture makes it difficult to position on high terrain. Especially on arch-like structures.

Comment: I especially hate the Abductor ship - it always shows the roof when you try to view the second internal floor, effectively hiding your guys from you.

Comment: If you want to move to a particular spot, pay attention to where it WOULD be drawn on the screen if the roof weren't in the way. You should be able to mouse onto that spot and move your soldier there.

Comment: The d-pad performs the same function on the consoles.

Comment: I have had a very frustrating time with this as well, and use the method you mentioned to reduce the annoyance somewhat, but it's a small help at best.
I *really* would've expected this to be patched by now.  As great of a game as XCOM is, Firaxis is losing big points for every day they let big issues like this go unaddressed.

Comment: I find using G and T to zoom can sometimes help get past the roof while still keeping the second floor selected.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that on some maps, the "what level the cursor wants to stick to" and the "what level is being drawn" are off by one, as mentioned in the other answer. e.g. the movement cursor is sticking to level 2 but the game is drawing level 3 (the roof).

There are two methods to get around this in these cases:

Say you have a soldier that you are trying to place onto a tile at level 2:

1 - put the "cursor level" too low, at level 1, so that the "visibility level" is correct, at level 2, and then rotate the map with Q and E such that *no tiles* at level 1 are lined up behind the tile on level 2 you wish to move to. With no level 1 tile to prioritize, the cursor will stick to level 2. I have never encountered (so far) a map where I was unable to find an appropriate angle, but it is a pain.

2 - put the "cursor level" correctly, at level 2, so that the "visibility level" is too high, at level 3 (the roof), and the blindly click through the roof. On some maps, this is actually easier than the first option. You can put the cursor level at 1, where you can see level 2, place the mouse over the tile you wish to move to eventually, go up a level with the scroll wheel, which will make the cursor stick to the correct level but draw the roof on top, and just eyeball-double-check that the 3-D cursor box outline appears where you think it should, and click.

Comment: Also note, for those playing on laptops, that F moves the visibility level up, and C moves the visibility level down, which gives much more control than edge or two-finger scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of which height-level is currently selected, if your target box jumps down the edges of platform it means that you selected the lower level (which you probably did because the roof of the UFO was in the way and you couldn't see your soldier).

I have not tried it yet, but on PC you can also zoom in and out (forgot the hotkeys now, zoom out was 'g' I think), so you can both see your soldiers and still have the appropriate level selected. (as mentioned before, rotation with 'q' and 'e' also can help you see your soldier)

Otherwise you can always maneuver semi-blindly (you still see the outline of your other soldiers on that level).